why after deploying python flask to the app engine it says Service Unavailable
after deployed the website says Service Unavailable and i checking the errors showing
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

at ._find_and_load_unlocked ( <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:984 )
at ._find_and_load ( <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007 )
at ._gcd_import ( <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1030 )
at .import_module ( /layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127 )
at .import_app ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py:371 )
at .load_wsgiapp ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:48 )
at .load ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:58 )
at .wsgi ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:67 )
at .load_wsgi ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:146 )
at .init_process ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:134 )
at .init_process ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py:95 )
at .spawn_worker ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:609 )

&
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

at .reap_workers ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:530 )
at .handle_chld ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:242 )
at .stop ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:396 )
at .halt ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:342 )
at .run ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:229 )
at .run ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:72 )
at .run ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:236 )
at .run ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:67 )
at .<module> ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/gunicorn:8 )

this is my folder structure

this my app.yaml
runtime: python39

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto


you're not running the command in the right folder. make sure you specify your folder. Didn't use yaml before, I might be wrong, but the error says it cannot find the file. Maybe run the yaml file from the folder itself.
